# residue for second order pole

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about evaluating the residue of the second-order pole. Suppose we have a function $f(z)$, which satisfies $f(z_0)=0$ and $f'(z_0) \neq 0$. Define $g(z) = 1/[f(z)]^2$, which has a second-order pole at $z_0$. In order to calculate the residue of $g(z)$ at $z_0$, we can use the formula
\begin{equation}
Res[g(z),z_0] = \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \left\{ \frac{d}{dz}\left[(z-z_0)^2 g(z)\right] \right\}.
\end{equation}
By substituting the definition of $g(z)$ and evaluate the derivative explicitly, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Res[g(z),z_0] &= \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \left\{ 2(z-z_0)g(z) + (z-z_0)^2 g'(z) \right\}\\
&= 2\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \left\{ \frac{z-z_0}{[f(z)]^2} - \frac{(z-z_0)^2f'(z)}{[f(z)]^3} \right\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Using L' Hospital's rule, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Res[g(z),z_0] &= 2\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\left\{ \frac{1}{2f(z)f'(z)} - \frac{2(z-z_0)f'(z) + (z-z_0)^2f''(z)}{3[f(z)]^2f'(z)} \right\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Here, the first term in the brackets is divergent due to $f(z)$ appears in the denominator.
So my question is that is there anything wrong with my derivation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try combining the two fractions. make the common denominator $6f(z)^2f'(z)$

Comment: thank you very much for your comments. I solved the problem and the final answer is $-f''(z_0)/[f'(z_0)]^3$ if I didn't make any mistake in the derivation.

Comment: yay good job! yeah I made that suggestion because you clearly hadn’t gone wrong (yet?) so you just needed to rewrite whatever you had